# Display HLL C when debugging Linux kernel source with TRACE32

Tags: jtag, trace32

I am debugging with Linux kernel LTS4.4 (arm32, cortexa7).

I already built successfully the kernel image as well as vmlinux.

I am using Debugger Lauterbach and Trace32 tool.
And use below command to load **vmlinux** and **kernel source**

```
B:: data.load.Elf /home/compile-kernel/linux-4.4.138/vmlinux /PlusVM /STRIPPART 4 /PATH "/home/src-kernel"
```

[image]

The loading progress is successful, but I don't see any **C code** (HLL), only **asm**.

After that, I try to show *symbol.list.source*
. However, the table **List** is empty.

Could you guys support me on this ! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you've build the kernel with debug information?

Comment: Yes. To be able to do Linux aware debugging, the vmlinux file must be compiled with debug info enabled. Thus, need to ensure that CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO is enabled in the kernel configuration. Probably find this option under “Kernel hacking -> Compile the kernel with debug info” (in newer kernel versions under “Kernel hacking -> Compile-time checks and compiler options -> Compile the kernel with debug info”). Make sure that CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED is not set (Reduce debugging information).

Comment: Well, if sYmbol.List.SOURCE is showing you an empty window, you are probably still missing required debug information in your vmlinux file. A suitable vmlinux file should be about 10 times bigger the raw image file. In you screenshot TRACE32 is still loading the file (there is the orange progress bar a the bottom) Have you waited long enough?

Comment: Hi Holger, of course I have waited for the progress completed. I just took the picture randomly for example.

Comment: https://www.lauterbach.com/frames.html?manual.html

Comment: I have corrected STRIPPART to resolve the issue.
This param indicates how many folder levels you must shift to reach the kernel-source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load Kernel Symbols:

Step 1:

- vmlinux

build/tmp/work/.../linux-kernel-standard-build/arch/arm/boot/vmlinux

- kernel source

build/tmp/work/.../linux-kernel-standard-build/source

Step 2:

Data.LOAD.Elf /home/user/build/tmp/work/.../linux-kernel-standard-build/arch/arm/boot/vmlinux /NoCODE **/STRIPPART "arch"** /SOURCEPATH /home/user/build/tmp/work/.../linux-kernel-standard-build/source

Result:

[image]